# Pulp (Python) Value Error: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, python-2.7, pulp

I'm trying to solve this problem http://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/ORMM/models/unit/linear/subunits/workforce/ using PuLP on Python.

This is my code:

```
from pulp import *

# Create the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
prob = LpProblem("The Bus Problem",LpMinimize)

# The variables are created with a lower limit of zero
x0=LpVariable("Number of drivers at time 0",0,None,LpInteger)
x4=LpVariable("Number of drivers at time 4",0)
x8=LpVariable("Number of drivers at time 8",0)
x12=LpVariable("Number of drivers at time 12",0)
x16=LpVariable("Number of drivers at time 16",0)
x20=LpVariable("Number of drivers at time 20",0)

# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += x0 + x4 + x8 + x12 + x16 + x20, "drivers"

# The five constraints are entered
prob += x0 + x4 >= 8, 
prob += x4 + x8 >= 10, 
prob += x8 + x12 >= 7, 
prob += x12 + x16 >= 12,
prob += x16 + x20 >= 4,

# The problem data is written to an .lp file
prob.writeLP("BusModel.lp")

# The problem is solved using PuLP's choice of Solver
prob.solve()
```

However, when I run this I get the error :

> File "C:\Users___\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py", line 1337, in **iadd**
>       other, name = other
>
> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

When I go and look at pulp.py, this is what it says in the code:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, tuple):
            other, name = other
        else:
            name = None
        if other is True:
            return self
        if isinstance(other, LpConstraintVar):
            self.addConstraint(other.constraint)
        elif isinstance(other, LpConstraint):
            self.addConstraint(other, name)
        elif isinstance(other, LpAffineExpression):
            if self.objective is not None:
                warnings.warn("Overwriting previously set objective.")
            self.objective = other
            self.objective.name = name
        elif isinstance(other, LpVariable) or isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            if self.objective is not None:
                warnings.warn("Overwriting previously set objective.")
            self.objective = LpAffineExpression(other)
            self.objective.name = name
        else:
            raise TypeError("Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects")
        return self
```

Can anyone see any obvious issues? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding *single-element tuples* here:

```
prob += x0 + x4 >= 8, 
prob += x4 + x8 >= 10, 
prob += x8 + x12 >= 7, 
prob += x12 + x16 >= 12,
prob += x16 + x20 >= 4,
```

The comma makes each expression into a tuple with one element. Either remove the comma (to leave it to the `__iadd__` method to set the name to `None`), or provide a name element after each comma.

Comment: Wow, as simple as removing the commas. Thanks so much!